# Reload tags file Vim

Tags: vim, tags, ctags

How do i reload the `tags` file from within Vim?

Is a restart necessary?

Comment: No need to reload it, vim does not keep it in memory. It will rather perform some binary search of the file each time you are looking for a tag.

Comment: Days before, I have to do Vim restart to make new `tags` file take effect. Vim version: `7.2`

Comment: Maybe had multiple tags files in different sub directories and were regenerating the wrong one?

Comment: It looks like it isn't stored in memory, but I just came to the same conclusion before realising that I'd spelt my object name wrong (which is why it wasn't finding it)!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to `:help tag-binary-search`, the tags file is binary (or linear) searched on each lookup, so there's no need to reload the file:

```
                                                        *tag-binary-search*
Vim uses binary searching in the tags file to find the desired tag quickly
(when enabled at compile time |+tag_binary|).  But this only works if the
tags file was sorted on ASCII byte value.  Therefore, if no match was found,
another try is done with a linear search.  If you only want the linear search,
reset the 'tagbsearch' option.  Or better: Sort the tags file!

Note that the binary searching is disabled when not looking for a tag with a
specific name.  This happens when ignoring case and when a regular expression
is used that doesn't start with a fixed string.  Tag searching can be a lot
slower then.  The former can be avoided by case-fold sorting the tags file.
See 'tagbsearch' for details.
```

Comment: i'm sorry, but where is that stated in your quote?

Comment: I guess it's implied (why would it binary search in the tags file if the file was loaded into memory at some point?).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know it is not necessary Vim 7.3 use the `tags` file as soon as it has been generated.

Answer (score 1):

I find it helps to just load the tags file in another buffer/tab.  Then I can re-load that buffer with `:e!` to get vim to see my tag updates.

Comment: This worked for me! (probably because I created the tags file after opening vim).